# how to loop generate a html line to each object in a list

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, xml, foreach

I need to create a table where each loop will populate the columns in an html table
obs. the parameter received in `onSuccess` function is a xml return

```
function onSuccess(data) {
    var table = document.getElementBdyId("kaizens")
    var lstProjetos = data.d.results;
    $.each(lstProjetos, function (key, value) {
        $("#head").append("</th>"+value.Area+"</th>");
    });
```

Html:

```
<div class="mytable">
    <table class="table" id="kaizens">
        <tr id="head">
            <th>teste</th>
        </tr>
        </table>
</div>
```

Comment: At first, JS is case-sensitive, `Kaizens !== kaizens`, then `td` elements needs to be wrapped in `tr` elements, then append the rows to the table.

Comment: You need to define row/s in your table first and then populate the cells/columns in it. Add a <tr> tag you html code and append the <td> tags dynamically to it.

Comment: I changed it but it still doesn't show anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`</th>` should be `<th>` without the `/`.
because balise should be open without the `/` and close with

```
function onSuccess(data) {
    var table = document.getElementById("kaizens")
    var lstProjetos = data.d.results;
    $.each(lstProjetos, function (key, value) {
        $("#head").append("<th>"+value.Area+"</th>");
    });
```

Comment: I found that I was closing a wrong {} in another part of the code, but I thank everyone who responded <3